# Why is not my discord code working? When i run the progam, it gives an error saying: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.11

Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


bot = discord.bot(command_prefix="!", help_command=None)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot logged in as {bot.user}")
    
            
            
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

The error i am getting:

```
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\coding\discord\server bots\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    bot = discord.bot(command_prefix="!", help_command=None)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I haven't coded in a while and i just got back to coding. I tried a simple discord.py program but it didn't seem to work. Is there any way i could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `commands.Bot()` with `from discord.ext import commands` before (which is your case).
Also don't forget to specify the intents.

Answer (score 1):

yeah, you need to specify intents
here is the code to it works

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", help_command=None, intents = intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot logged in as {bot.user}")
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"hi {ctx.author.mention}")


bot.run("token")
```